# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, swing, rsa

Пишу программу шифрование/расшифровка сообщения по методу RSA.
При реализации расшифровки выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Код:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                {

                    String[] mas = textField_1.getText().split(String.valueOf(new char[]{' '}));

                    String s1 = new String();
                    for (String s : mas)
                    {
                        int Menc = Integer.parseInt(s.trim()),
                                d = Integer.parseInt(textField_5.getText()),
                                N = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText()),
                                Mdec = Exponentiation.ModPow(Menc, d, N);

                        s1 += (char) (Mdec);
                        textField_R.setText(s1);

                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: один из `s.trim()` `textField_5.getText()` и `textField_2.getText()` пустое

Comment: Очевидно, что одно из значения которые вы пытаетесь преобразовать к int пустое. Дебаг вам в помощь, смотрите какое именно, а дальше уже почему оно пустое.

Comment: @Saidolim они заполнены, поэтому я не пойму , почему эта ошибка выходит.

Comment: в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @Saidolim судя  по Debag, который  виснет на строке `s1 += (char)(Mdec)`, видимо в s1 проблема

Comment: поменяйте `String s1 = new String();` на `String s1 = "";` или `s1 = (char) (Mdec);` на  `s1.append((char) (Mdec))`

Answer (score 1):

С помощью Debug нашла ошибку

```
  String[] mas = textField_1.getText().split(" ");
```

Разбивает строку на подстроки и заполняет массив, одни их этих подстрок оказывались пустыми.